# Show if Arrow price vector $\pi$ exists, then the law of one price hold

Tags: asset-pricing

Now, the proof I have read goes like this:

Take assets 1 and 2, entirely identical. By assumption there is a pricing vector, i.e. $\sum_s\pi_sd^1_s=q^1$ and $\sum_s\pi_sd^2_s=q^2$ where $d^i_j$ is the payoff of asset $i$ in state $j$ and $\pi_i$ is the $i$-th element of the pricing vector $\vec{\pi}$. Since $d^1_s=d^2_s$ for all $s$ (identical assets), we must have $q^1=q^2$.

---

My question about this proof is that the assumption does not say only one $\vec{\pi}$ exists. It seems possible to me that there can be another price vector and we would have got a different price for the same asset. For example, price vector $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,3,4)$.

Answer (score 1):

By pricing vector I assume you refer to the **state price vector**, whose definition can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_prices).

According to the above definition, the price of a particular state specifically refers to the the price of a contract paying exactly one unit of numeraire if that state does occur and zero unit otherwise. And **state price vector** is thus the vector of state prices for all states.

So it seems to me that this **state price vector** is kind of normalized, only one specific **state price vector** exists for a given measure. Thus if two assets are identical (providing exactly same cash flows under any state), their price should be equal to each other no matter what. I think this is the point of the law of one price.